# TFS - Create alerts for successful release to specifc environment

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-alerts

How can I create an alert in TFS that sends an email to someone when a release is successful to a particular environment?  In particular, I would like VSTS to send an email to the QA Team manager when a build is sucessfully released to the TEST environment, the second of three environments.

Intuitively, I would expect a 'Release' option in the 'Alert Category' dropdown but there is not.

We are currently using MS VSTFS Version 14.95.25229.0

Comment: So are you using TFS or VSTS? They're different things.

Comment: We are using on-prem TFS.  We are attempting to configure the alert through the hosted website, which is labeled "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015".  The version that I provided in the original question, specifies TFS 2015 Update 2.1.  Should I alter the VSTS in my question to VSTFS?

Comment: Do you receive the email alert after configuring it in release definition and trigger the release.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure it in release definition:

1. Open/create a release definition
2. Click … of specific environment > Deployment Conditions/Configure variables

[image]

3. Click General tab and configure

[image]

Comment: Further evidence that a team working in total isolation builds the "Releases" section of TFS.

Comment: Who will the notification be sent to? There is nowhere to enter email addresses.